# Probability that a natural number is a k-th power

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like to determine the probability that a natural number is a k-th power. It is quite straightforward to see that the probability for a natural number less than N to be a I-that power is
$$N^{1/k-1}$$

However I do not understand what to do to extend it for N going to infinity. I essentially though of cutting dyadically or so, and sum the « local » probability above...

Comment: There is no such thing as a uniformly random natural number.

Comment: I think that by probability, you mean the limit of #$\{ n \leq N | n \text{ is a $k$-th power}\} / N$ for $N \to \infty$? You should specify this in your post.